# What is the most secure way to store sessions with Django?

Tags: django, django-sessions

What Django session engine should I use for enhanced security?

Answer (score 1):

If by "secure" you mean you need to store data with low chance of loss, i.e.  **durability** then the `db` or `cached_db` backends are the best ones. (`file` is generally to be avoided apart from in unusual circumstances, `cache` is designed for data that is closer to throwaway in nature, and `signed_cookies` depends too much on browser/user behaviour)

If you mean you want to store data **privately**, with no chance of a third party seeing it, and the attacks you envisage to be most likely are against your server and not user computers, then `signed_cookies` is probably the best (or directly use [set_signed_cookie](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponse.set_signed_cookie) rather than use the session), because you won't be storing the data on your server at all. You need to be aware of the limitations of cookies.

If you mean you want to store data **privately**, but the attacks you envisage to be most likely are against your users' computers, then `signed_cookies` is out because the data in the cookies can be read easily by someone with access to the cookies in a browser. The cookie data is signed, but not encrypted.

If you care about data **integrity** i.e. that it cannot be tampered with, either by an attacker or by the user, then the different backends provide similar levels of assurance: signed cookies are difficult to tamper with due to the use of a MAC, and the database backend is difficult because an attacker shouldn't have access to the database (and if they do you probably have bigger problems).

In short, you need to know which specific security properties you are interested in, and what attack vectors you are considering.

Answer (score 0):

TLDR; The `db` session engine seems to be the most secure, but the backups need to be created with a special care.

---

Django comes with these session engines:

- `django.contrib.sessions.backends.db`
- `django.contrib.sessions.backends.file`
- `django.contrib.sessions.backends.cache`
- `django.contrib.sessions.backends.cached_db`
- `django.contrib.sessions.backends.signed_cookies`

In addition, you can write your own or use a third party like `django-redis-sessions`.

After a little research, I found that only the `db` and `file` engines have the
`clear_expired` method implemented. This method is called when you call the `clearsessions` management command.

So when you use other session engines, the information that belongs to users who left the website without logging out, it's still possible to read what was in their sessions.

You can use the `file` session engine only on a single server, which doesn't work for scaling. So, my most secure choice is to use the `db` session engine and ensure that the `django_session` table is excluded from the database backups with the PostgreSQL pg_dump `--exclude-table-data` parameter.